# tmux open terminal failed: not a terminal

Tags: shell, tmux, systemd

I have a shell script that is enabled as service to start multiple shell scripts e.g.

```
service started script -> script1, script2 ,script3
```

script1 should open a program in a tmux window, and it does work just fine if I manually start the script via `./script1.sh`, however when started at boot via the service started script it does not with the above error:

```
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well a service would traditionally not have an associated tty (terminal). Its a multi user OS, no one is logged in yet, whose terminal would it write to? Why do these services need an interactive shell?

Comment: There are many scripts doing different things backups etc... however the one in question runs a minecraft server in a tmux window

Comment: Okay well post the tmux bits of the script, by default it will try to attach to the current tty (which doesn't exist hence the error) if you have a new session in there for example you'll need to add a -d param to prevent this

Comment: tmux new -s minecraft "java -args minecarft.jar nogui"

Comment: Try tmux new -d -s minecraft "java -args minecarft.jar nogui"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the issue is that the service does not have an associated tty. A workaround I've found is to change your tmux call in your script to

```
tmux new-session -s username -d
```

(username a user for whom the service was started)

Comment: the option `-d` doesn't always work (I have a case with a remote server that fails with the same error: **`open terminal failed: not a terminal`**)

Comment: For sure results vary, this worked for me though.  I was trying to run tmux at startup while using .bash_profile to start a openbox kiosk.

Answer (score 52):

There is an answer already [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67537/prevent-ssh-client-passing-term-environment-variable-to-server), but [this link](http://jordanelver.co.uk/blog/2010/11/27/automatically-attaching-to-a-tmux-session-via-ssh/) I think summarises it better. In a nutshell, use the `-t` flag:

```
ssh -t host tmux attach
```

If you want to set it into your `.ssh/config` file, look in the `ssh_config` manpage for the `RequestTTY` option:

```
 RequestTTY
         Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session.  The
         argument may be one of: ``no'' (never request a TTY), ``yes''
         (always request a TTY when standard input is a TTY), ``force''
         (always request a TTY) or ``auto'' (request a TTY when opening a
         login session).  This option mirrors the -t and -T flags for
         ssh(1).
```

Comment: While this answer has answers I was googling for, the question doesn't actually involve SSH; it's about startup scripts.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [p10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) as a zsh theme, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/1203#issuecomment-754805535), you should put this stanza in the top of .zsrc:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  exec tmux new-session -A -s workspace
fi
```